OAuth V2.0 login window with Insider Ring banner on top does not show enter password screen, it keeps showing Enter username screen in loop
I am facing below issue:

I am trying to login into Desktop application written in .Net8 WPF & integrated with MSAL OAuth v2.0.

When I launch the app, it shows org sign-in window with username textbox.

As soon as I enter my username and press next, instead of showing Enter password screen, it reloads the sign-in screen with username text box again.


I have tried logging in into same application from another machine and it was successful there.
Only difference between my machine and other machine was, I was getting Insider Ring - details here banner on right top corner for sign in screen on my machine.
Has anyone faced this issue before? Do we have any solution for this?
I have tried clearing browser cache and setting different browser as default browser, but still the same issue.
